# Segue not working

Tags: swift

I am making an iOS app in swift where I have a tableView with cells, what I want is to transit to another view controller when I click on the cell. Here is my code block for the segue source.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "selectedEvent"{
        let cellIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow();
        let tempIndex = cellIndex?.row
        let name = eventsManager.createdEvents[tempIndex!].name
        let address = eventsManager.createdEvents[tempIndex!].address
        let latD = eventsManager.createdEvents[tempIndex!].eventLat
        let lonD = eventsManager.createdEvents[tempIndex!].eventLon
        let coords = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latD, lonD)
    }
    println("segue fired")
}
```

Here is the code in the segue destination.

```
@IBAction func showOnMap(segue: UIStoryboardSegue){
        println("segue check")
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("selectedEvent", sender: self)
        let showEventController = segue.sourceViewController as EventListViewController
        let focusAddress = showEventController.address
        let position = showEventController.coords
        let name = showEventController.name
        var marker = GMSMarker(position: position!)
        println("is marker working? I hope so")
        marker.title = name
        marker.map = self.mapView
}
```

The println statements are to check if the segue is firing and the first statement "segue fired" prints on the console, and the view in the simulator switches to the destination viewController. Unfortunately, the 2nd part of the code does not execute and I am having trouble figuring out why.

Comment: You want to change ViewController when you select a cell, then what's the code in `tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath`?

Answer (score 0):

The `println("segue check")` line will only print if the code inside `IBAction` is triggered by an event. Make sure `IBAction` is connected to the proper object in your view controller's view.

Comment: I think the segue is connected? Cause when I select the cell, the view controllers change from the source to destination but the data just doesnt appear to be sent over.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("selectedEvent", sender: self)` at the destination view controller's `showOnMap` function and then appear to be getting an instance of the view controller where you came from?

If you want to save data in your segue destination, you should first define variables in your destination's view controller and then save it at the destination in your `prepareForSegue` above. Something like this:

```
if segue.identifier == "selectedEvent"{
    ...
    let coords = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latD, lonD)
    ...
    let myDestVC = segue.destinationViewController as MyDestinationViewController
    let myDestVC.coords = coords
    ...
}
```

Once you've got all your data saved, you can use them where ever you want in your destination's view controller. If you want to use them immediately, you can do so by overriding `viewDidLoad` `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`,

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. Should I then create a new function to display the data or can I just pass it into viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear? Will this cause the app to the display the data straight away or only when the segue is performed?

Comment: Probably best to put it in viewDidLoad if you want the display set before you see it.